# Unable to unzip the zipped files using zlib module

Tags: node.js, zlib

I am trying to unzip the files from the zipped data using node build-in module `zlib`, for some reason I am not able to unzip it, I am getting an error as follows:

```
Error: incorrect header check
test.js:53
No debug adapter, can not send 'variables'
```

The code I am trying is as follows:

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = './Divvy_Trips_2019_Q2.zip';

var str1 = fs.createReadStream(filename);

var gzip = zlib.createGunzip();

str1.pipe(gzip).on('data', function (data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The URL to the zipped data is as follows: [Divvy_Trips_2019_Q2.zip](https://divvy-tripdata.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GZip (`.gz`) and ZIP (`.zip`) are different formats. You need a library that handles ZIP files, like [yauzl](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl).

```js
// https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl/blob/master/examples/dump.js

const yauzl = require("yauzl");

const path = "./Divvy_Trips_2019_Q2.zip";

yauzl.open(path, function(err, zipfile) {
  if (err) throw err;
  zipfile.on("error", function(err) {
    throw err;
  });
  zipfile.on("entry", function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    console.log(entry.getLastModDate());
    if (/\/$/.exec(entry)) return;
    zipfile.openReadStream(entry, function(err, readStream) {
      if (err) throw err;
      readStream.pipe(process.stdout);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So it is not possible to do this with the built-in libraries, Do I need to install this package, is there any alternatives with the built-in node modules?

Comment: Yes, you need to install a third-party library (with npm or Yarn). Node.js has a minimal built-in library on purpose, so most projects will use external packages.